# Implementation of apriori with spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apriori, bigdata

I intend to implement the Apriori algorithm according to YAFIM article with pySpark.  It contains with two phases in processing workflow:

1. First, the set of frequent 1-itemsets is found by scanning the database to accumulate the count for each item, and collecting those items that satisfy minimum support.

[1]: http://bayanbox.ir/download/2410687383784490939/phase1.png phase-1

2. Phase 2: in  this  phase,  we  iteratively  using  k-frequent itemsets to generate (k+1)-frequent itemsets.

[2]: http://bayanbox.ir/view/6380775039559120652/phase2.png phase-2

To implement the first phase I have written the following code:

```
from operator import add
transactions = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/wo7gkiza1500361138466/T10I4D100K.dat").cache()
minSupport = 0.05 * transactions.count()
items = transactions.flatMap(lambda line:line.split(" "))
itemCount = items.map(lambda item:(item, 1)).reduceByKey(add)
l1 = itemCount.filter(lambda (i,c): c > minSupport)
l1.take(5)  

output: [(u'', 100000), (u'494', 5102), (u'829', 6810), (u'368', 7828), (u'766', 6265)]
```

My problem is that I have no idea for implementing the second phase, and especially getting the candidate set item.

For example, suppose we have the following RDD (frequent 3-itemsets):

```
([1, 4, 5], 7), ([1, 4, 6], 6), ...
```

We want to find the candidate 4-itemsets so that if in the 3-itemsets, the two first items is the same, you will have four items available as follows:

```
[1, 4, 5, 6], ...
```

Comment: Is there a reason for re-implementing the algorithm? The mllib contains all those algorithms for *Frequent itemsets, association rules, and sequential pattern mining*

Comment: @AKSW The mlib only contains FP-growth. I want to implement this for the curriculum. thanks for your answer

Comment: My issue with this question is that the article that you are mentioning isn't accessible. Thus there is lots of bits from the second part that are too broad to figure out. By consequence makes your question as well broad unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @eliasah my problem  in the second part is how to get the candidate's itemsets. I uploaded the article and I hope your help. http://bayanbox.ir/view/5497148585950138559/YAFIM-A-Parallel-Frequent-Itemset-Mining-Algorithm-with-Spark.pdf